# Как работать с содержимым стека?

Tags: стек, c++

Создал стек. В нем есть функция push():

```
void push(char a)
{
    if(top < maxSize) stack_array[top++] = a;
    else
    {
        cout << "Stack is FULL!";
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Вот я поместил в стек элементы. Как сейчас с ними мне работать? Хочу проверить например, есть ли внутри стека символ '*'. Как сделать?

Сделал так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    chr = str[i];
    N1.push(chr);

    if(char N1.push(chr) == '*') k++; // <- Вот так
    cout << k;
}
```

но пишет: expected an '=', на точку в N1.push(chr)

Comment: С содержимым стека никто не работает. В стек можно добавить элемент (push), взять верхний элемент (pull). Вам нужен либо список, либо необходимо реализовать поверх стека перебор элементов - делается это переливкой из стека во временный стек и обратно, такое использование стека не оптимально.

Answer (score 2):

Вся прелесть стека в том и заключается, что за единицу времени можно работать только с верхним элементом: извлекать его, извлекать его, чтобы извлечь последующие элементы и т.д.
Это принцип LIFO( Last In First Out ), по которому и работает стек. Если вам надо за единицу времени получать элементы, расположенные ниже первого, то используйте другую структуру данных( массив, список, вектор и т.д ).

Answer (score 0):

Что за странный код:

```
if(char N1.push(chr) == '*') k++;
```

?

Функция `Push` для того, чтобы поместить элемент в стек, а не достать его. Не помню порядок операций, но вполне возможно что этот код создаёт `char N1` а потом пытается запустить у `char` метод `push`, что естественно невозможно.

Для того, чтобы "вынуть" элемент из стека необходимо описать другую функцию, например "pull", которая будет "снимать" элемент с вершины стека. Причём согласно описанию структуры стека тот элемент, который ты снимаешь должен быть удалён из стека.

Для простого просмотра стека без его изменения можно ввести пару других функций, использовать паттерн итератор, или например запрос элемента по его индексу.

Да, и если нужен простой просмотр, без алгоритма работы со стеком (Первый Пришёл - Последний Ушёл), то следует использовать простой список.

Comment: @delphist007 а как тогда мне проверить содержимое стека? Ну чтобы узнать есть ли там символ * или нет?

Comment: Вытаскивать все по одному элементу (или перекладывать в другой стек), пока не найдешь нужный.

Comment: @navi1893, я уже написал, что нужно дополнить класс функциями для его простого просмотра, например:

    public int getCapacity(){
      return top;
    }

    public char getElementByIndex(int index){
        if(top < maxSize) return stack_array[top++];
        else
        {
            cout << "Нет такого элемента"<<endl;
        }
    }

    ...

    
    for(int i = 0; i < N1.getCapacity(); i++)
    {
      if(N1.getElementByIndex(i) == '*') cout<<"Нашёл!"<<endl;
    }

Но я тогда не совсем понимаю, зачем нужен именно стек в таком случае?

Comment: создаю обратную польскую запись. И чтобы сделать его, мне нужно рассмотреть элементы стека

Comment: @navi1893, Для этого тебе не нужно его просматривать. Стек используется примерно в таком алгоритме:

    Для каждого элемента вычисляемой строки:
      если элемент - число, то поместить его в стек (stack.push(element))
      если элемент - операция, то вытащить из стека два числа num1=stack.pull(), num2=stack.pull(),выполнить с ними соответствующую операцию, а результат положить обратно в стек (result=num1*num2, stack.push(result)).

В конце, в стеке останется единственное число, это и есть ответ.

Это так, на глаз, с учётом того, что операции только бинарные (работают с двумя элементами).

Comment: А со стеком, тогда не изобретай велосипед, а используй шаблон stack.